# how to extract letters and numbers with above 90% from a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

[image]

here is my code:

```
S='MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); CITIGROUP INC (83%);' 
lst = re.findall('\S+[9]\S+', S)
lst
```

My code should return a string with letters and percentages with above 90%, in my example it should not return CITIGROUP INC (83%);

my output:
I was just able to return the percentages above 90 but not the letters.

```
['(95%);', '(91%);']
```

my expected output:

```
MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import re

S='MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); CITIGROUP INC (83%);'
lst = re.findall(r'.*? \((?:9\d|[1-9]\d{2,})%\);', S)
```

It gives:

```
['MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%);', ' MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%);']
```

If you want to concatenate the results into a single string then you can add

```
''.join(lst)
```

It will give:

```
'MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%);'
```

Comment: I think it should accept `100%` as well? Or even above?

Comment: @HaoWu Good point. Now it will accept any higher number.

Answer (score 0):

`\S` only matches non whitespace, and since you have whitespaces before the percentage it won't match them.

One way of solving this would be matching for anything until you get a parentheses followed by a percentage that starts with a nine followed by one of `[0-9]` or `\d`:

`lst = re.findall('.+?\(9\d%\);', S)`

However, if you want to make a more complicated logic I'd suggest using match and capturing group

example:

```
import re


S='MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); CITIGROUP INC (83%);'
lst = re.finditer('.+?\((\d+)%\);', S)

for item in lst:
    if int(item[1]) > 90:
        print(item[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by `;` and parse the number value if above 90%.

- Can read beyond 100% percentages
- Can read both positive and negative percentages
- Can read decimal point values

```
S = 'MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); CITIGROUP INC (83%); ABCDE CORP (200%); DEFG HI (19%); DEFG HI (-96%); JK LMN (90.12%);'

def is_above_90(text):
    if not text.strip():
        return False
    start = text.rindex('(') + 1
    end = text.rindex('%')
    num = text[start:end]
    return float(num) >= 90

s_splits = S.split(';')
s_splits_filtered = filter(is_above_90, s_splits)
S_filtered = ";".join(s_splits_filtered)

print(S_filtered)
```

```
MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); ABCDE CORP (200%); JK LMN (90.12%)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
S='MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); CITIGROUP INC (83%); ANOTHER (100%)' 
out = []
for s in S.split(';'):
    s = s.strip()
    if re.search(r'\(9[0-9]%|\(1[0-9]{2}%', s):
        out.append(s)
        
print(out)
print('; '.join(out))
```

**Output:**

```
# list
['MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%)', 'MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%)', 'ANOTHER (100%)']

# string
MOL MAGYAR OLAJ-ES GAZIPARI RT (95%); MERRILL LYNCH & CO INC (91%); ANOTHER (100%)
```